# Return last N rows in Ascending Order without using a Subquery

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I would like to return the last `N` rows from a table and order it by `id` (PK) in ascending order.

The conventional wisdom is to prepare a query in the following manner:

```
--- Get last N rows in Ascending Order 
SELECT t1.*
FROM (

    SELECT *
    FROM table t
    ORDER BY t.id DESC
    LIMIT N
    
) t1
ORDER BY t1.id ASC
```

The reason I want to avoid subqueries (in this instance) is my ORM (Doctrine) does not support this AFAIK.

I currently have a workaround to run the result of the inner query through `array_reverse()` but would like to know if there's a more elegant solution to this.

---

**Symfony4 & Doctrine 2.8**

My attempt are to run the subquery in the above fashion results in an error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 41 near 'JOIN (SELECT': Error: Subquery is not supported here

```
$sub = $this->createQueryBuilder('t2')
    ->select('t2')
    ->orderBy('t2.id', 'DESC')
    ->setMaxResults($numRows);

$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t1')
    ->select('t3')
    ->innerJoin(
        sprintf('(%s)', $sub->getDQL()),
        't3',
        Expr\Join::ON,
        't1.id = t3.id'
    )
    ->orderBy('t3.id', 'ASC')
    ->setMaxResults($numRows);

$qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Which generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT t3 
FROM Ent1 t1 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT t2 FROM Ent1 t2 ORDER BY t2.id DESC
) t3 
ON t1.id = t3.id 
ORDER BY t3.id ASC
```

Comment: You can use SQL in Doctrine when you use [Native SQL](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/native-sql.html)

Comment: My use case is quite simple so I find the Native SQL approach a bit over complicated

Comment: You can do a [subquery in Doctrine](https://gist.github.com/roukmoute/d8b7473da78fc9d8b867)

Comment: @ArleighHix I may have been ambiguous. I didn't mean they don't support subqueries altogether. Just not mine. Help appreciated to reformat my sub-query

Comment: Well, since your "use case is quite simple" and you don't want to over complicate it then the `array_reverse()` workaround as a repository method is probably best.